# "even allowing" or "although allowing"

Tags: differences, language-formation

In the dictionary, the meaning of "allowing for" is " In consideration of sth". So in this sentence, "Even allowing for his age, he still acts very immaturely". Can I change the word “ even" into "although"? Why or why not?

Answer (score 1):

*Even* and *although* as well as having roughly opposite meaning (as invariant says) also have different syntax.

*Even* introduces a NP (noun phrase):

> I don't think even he would argue.
>
> Even seeing the notice didn't shut him up.

*Although* introduces a clause with a finite verb:

> Although he saw the notice, he didn't shut up

Answer (score 0):

No, because "although" is not a substitute for "even". It changes the meaning.

"Although" would be used to convey the opposite meaning. For example you might say, "Although, allowing for his age, he acts maturely".

Perhaps you are confusing "although" with "even though".